# Paypal Customer Dispute API - Provide Evidence always returns MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY

Tags: php, laravel, curl, paypal, guzzle

I've been trying to upload a pdf file when providing an evidence to [Paypal Disputes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/#disputes-actions_provide-evidence) in the Claim Stage after verifying that the dispute case has the `/provide-evidence` on its [HATEOAS links](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#api-responses), the curl code below works in the CLI:

```
 $ curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-12345/provide-evidence \
   -H "Content-Type: multipart/related" \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer {AccessToken}" \
   -F 'input={"evidences":[{"evidence_type": "PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT", "evidence_info": {"tracking_info": [{"carrier_name": "FEDEX", "tracking_number": "123456789"}]}, "notes": "Test"}]};type=application/json' \
   -F 'file1=@D:\Sample\storage\app\paypal\sample.pdf'
```

However when converted to PHP, either using `curl` or `guzzle` the API returns **`VALIDATION_ERROR - MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY`**, I've tried almost every possible approach, but the error is consistent.

**Using Guzzle:** (trying to copy the working curl above as much as possible, since Guzzle can't send `multipart/related` request, I had to [modify the content-type manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671390/2289953)).

```
$pdf = 'D:\Sample\storage\app\paypal\sample.pdf';

$input = [
  'evidences' => [
    [
      'evidence_type' => 'PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT',
      'evidence_info' => [
        'tracking_info' => [
          'carrier_name' => "FEDEX",
          'tracking_number' => '122533485'
        ]
      ],
      'notes' => 'Test',
    ],
  ]
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    'timeout'  => 2.0,
    'version' => 1.1
]);

$options = [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
  ],
  'multipart' => [
      [
          'name'     => 'input',
          'contents' => json_encode($input),
          'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
      ],
      [
          'name'     => 'file1',
          'contents' => fopen($pdf, 'r'),
          'filename' => 'sample.pdf',
          'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']
      ],
  ]
];

$url = '/v1/customer/disputes/'.$disputeId.'/provide-evidence';

$headers = isset($options['headers']) ? $options['headers'] : [];
$body = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream($options['multipart']);
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $url, $headers, $body, '1.1');

$modify['set_headers']['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/related; boundary=' . $request->getBody()->getBoundary();

$request = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\modify_request($request, $modify);

$response = $client->send($request);
```

The guzzle code above still return `{VALIDATION_ERROR - MISSING_OR_INVALID_REQUEST_BODY}` and same result when I just do a normal multipart/form-data request.

What could be the issue? Any ideas or suggestion would very much help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = [
  'evidences' => [
    [
      'evidence_type' => 'PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT',
      'evidence_info' => [
        'tracking_info' => [
          'carrier_name' => "FEDEX",
          'tracking_number' => '122533485'
        ]
      ],
      'notes' => 'Test',
    ],
  ]
];
```

This is your $input, if you `json_encode()` it, you get

```
{
    "evidences":
    [
        {
            "evidence_type":"PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT",
            "evidence_info":{
                "tracking_info":{
                    "carrier_name":"FEDEX",
                    "tracking_number":"122533485"
                }
            },
            "notes":"Test"
            
        }
    ]
    
}
```

which **does not** matches with your request body,

---

I have changed your $input by inserting another square bracket,

```
$input = [
  'evidences' => [
    [
      'evidence_type' => 'PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT',
      'evidence_info' => [
        'tracking_info' => [[
          'carrier_name' => "FEDEX",
          'tracking_number' => '122533485'
        ]]
      ],
      'notes' => 'Test',
    ],
  ]
];
```

Now it matches your curl request,

```
{
    "evidences":
        [
            {
                "evidence_type":"PROOF_OF_FULFILLMENT",
                "evidence_info":
                    {
                        "tracking_info":
                            [
                                {
                                    "carrier_name":"FEDEX",
                                    "tracking_number":"122533485"
                                    
                                }
                            ]    
                    },
                    "notes":"Test"             
            }
        ]
}
```

I hope it helps. If it doesn't work, then problem might lie somewhere else but the request body will match, you can try the guzzle call first.

Comment: thanks, my bad, i was too hooked up on the file upload and missed parts of my json data 